# How can I get ClientMetadata parameter values in Custom Message Lambda trigger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, triggers, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I am using Cognito's Custom message Lambda trigger to send a dynamic message before validation.I want to get tempPassword and applicationUrl values from ClientMetadata and encrypt them. As [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html) shows, clientMetadata is one of the Custom message request parameters. However, while the other parameters specified here are coming to the input of the Lambda, the clientMetadata parameter does not. Did I do something wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ClientMetadata is intended for you to pass custom data to the "Custom message" lambda function through an API operation, as per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-custom-message-request). If you don't pass any custom data, the field won't be present in the lambda input.

The following API operations allow passing the ClientMetadata:

- AdminResetUserPassword
- AdminRespondToAuthChallenge
- AdminUpdateUserAttributes
- ForgotPassword
- GetUserAttributeVerificationCode
- ResendConfirmationCode
- SignUp
- UpdateUserAttributes

Usage example, calling SignUp operation with ClientMetadata:

```
var params = {
  ClientId: '3n4b5urk1ft4fl3mg5e62d9ado'
  Password: 'PASSWORD'
  Username: 'jane@example.com'
  ClientMetadata: {
    'tempPassword': 'PASSWORD',
    'applicationUrl': 'example.com'
  },
  UserAttributes: [
    {
      Name: 'email',
      Value: 'jane@example.com'
    },
    {
      Name: 'name',
      Value: 'Jane'
    }
  ]
};

cognitoidentityserviceprovider.signUp(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

And then the lambda will receive such data within the `CustomMessage_SignUp` triggerSource:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // CustomMessage_SignUp : Custom message – To send the confirmation code post sign-up.
    if (event.triggerSource === 'CustomMessage_SignUp') {
      let tempPassword = event.request.clientMetadata.tempPassword; // 'PASSWORD'
      let applicationUrl = event.request.clientMetadata.applicationUrl; // 'example.com'
      ...
    }
}
```